# how to save a file exactly as it is from a String java

Tags: java, string, file

For example lets say i have the following String,

```
String str = "Patient: " + patient +
"\nMonth: " + month +
"\nDay : " + day +
"\nYear: " + year 
+"\nDescription: " + description;

//And I write this data to a file, 
PrintWriter outputFile = new PrintWriter("hello.txt");

outputFile.println(str);
```

Then the result on the file is just a single line, when I open it,
is there a way, to just do the format as the String passed into the file.?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You're on Windows, aren't 'cha?

Answer (score 2):

The \n works as expected on UNIX. Using Windows may require \r\n. Please view https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/29075/difference-between-n-and-r-n

Answer (score 1):

It worked for me just as written on a Linux system. If you are using a windows machine, try "\r\n" as new lines instead of just "\n". Also a good habit is to specify the encoding while opening a PrintWriter. Ideally you can use System.getProperty("line.separator") to get the platform dependent line separator.

```
String lineSeparator = System.getProperty("line.separator");
String str = "Patient: " + "a" +
            lineSeparator + "Month: " + "a" +
            lineSeparator + "Day : " + "a" +
            lineSeparator + "Year: " + "a"
            lineSeparator + "Description: " + "a";

    try {
        PrintWriter outputFile = new PrintWriter("hello.txt", "UTF-8");
        outputFile.println(str);
        outputFile.close();
        System.out.println("writing file");
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```